# how to convert decimal into string using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting some decimal results from my database but I would like to convert it into string. The value that is coming back from the database is like 2.500000 or 1.500000 but in this example, I want to show it like either 2.5 or 1.5

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"select DATEDIFF(minute, Min(myDate), Max(myDate)) / 60.0 as hours                 
                            from myTable
                            where userid = @UserID
                              and DT_Submitted = (select CAST(FLOOR( CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
                              and Checked = 1";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", tempUser.ToString());

        con.Open();
        decimal result = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        lblHours.Text = result.ToString() + " Hours";

        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the `ToString()` overload that takes a format string?

Comment: Please in future post a http://sscce.org/. There is no reason for your database code in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call one of the overloads of `ToString` that accepts a format string.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"select DATEDIFF(minute, Min(myDate), Max(myDate)) / 60.0 as hours                 
                            from myTable
                            where userid = @UserID
                              and DT_Submitted = (select CAST(FLOOR( CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
                              and Checked = 1";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", tempUser.ToString());

        con.Open();
        decimal result = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        lblHours.Text = result.ToString("0.#") + " Hours";

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

On a side note, you don't need to call `Dispose` on your connection because you are in a using block, which does that automatically. Still, you should call `Close`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to convert the decimal values to string:

```
num.ToString( "0.#" )
```

Comment: Wrong way round dude.

Answer (score 0):

If you want greater control over how a `decimal` needs to be represented in string format, then use the [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Here are the [standard numeric format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) rules and the [custom numeric formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) rules.